# Debezium - Custom Payload - MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Im using Debezium to sync data from MySQL to S3. Now I want to make some changes.

Sample insert:

```
create table new (id int);
insert into new (1);
```

### 1. Custom Payload

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        bla bla bla
        "optional": false,
        "name": "_72.31.84.129.test.new.Envelope"
    },
    "payload": {
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "id": 10
        },
        "source": {
            "version": "0.10.0.Final",
            "connector": "mysql",
            "name": "11.11.84.129",
            "ts_ms": 1576605998000,
            "snapshot": "false",
            "db": "test",
            "table": "new",
            "server_id": 1,
            "gtid": "3a7b90e9-207e-11ea-b3ed-121a0cbac3cb:51",
            "file": "mysql-bin.000003",
            "pos": 12770,
            "row": 0,
            "thread": 47,
            "query": null
        },
        "op": "c",
        "ts_ms": 1576605998231
    }
}
```

I want to only push the payload option with some custom changes. I need to include the `source,op,ts_ms` are inside the `payload.after`.

#### Expected output:

```
{
            "id": 10, 
            "source": {
            "version": "0.10.0.Final",
            "connector": "mysql",
            "name": "11.11.84.129",
            "ts_ms": 1576605998000,
            "snapshot": "false",
            "db": "test",
            "table": "new",
            "server_id": 1,
            "gtid": "3a7b90e9-207e-11ea-b3ed-121a0cbac3cb:51",
            "file": "mysql-bin.000003",
            "pos": 12770,
            "row": 0,
            "thread": 47,
            "query": null
        },
        "op": "c",
        "ts_ms": 1576605998231
        }
```

I don't want schema, payload.before. Im not sure how to get this output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [SMT](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html) for extracting the new record state. It will only propagate what's in `after`. Optionally, you can let it add chosen field from `source`, too.

```
...
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.unwrap.add.source.fields=table,lsn
...
```

You cannot insert the `op` and `ts_ms` fields atm., but they can be propgated as message headers.